# how to change accelerometer sampling time in android using java API other than standard SENSOR_DELAY_UI/FASTEST/GAME/NORMAL

Tags: android, android-sensors

i want to know the position value using accelerometer output. please answer my question

How to get constant sampling interval (because i am getting different time interval between different event values)

Answer (score 0):

> How to get constant sampling interval (because i am getting different time interval between different event values)

A "constant sampling interval" is not possible. You will get the data when the sensor elects to hand it to you (for `SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST`, which is no delay), and that will be up to the manufacturers of the sensor and the overall device. If you need to smooth out the data rate, you need to do that yourself somehow.

Comment: then how to get accurate velocity and position values from accelerometer, if the sampling interval is not constant.

Comment: You don't. That is basic physics.